# open cv image processing bounding box javascript

Tags: javascript, opencv, image-processing

I have this labeled image and I want to surround each colored with bounding box to find center of each object 
how can i do this with Open Cv library with python or javascript

[connected component labeled image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLznE.jpg)

I am a beginner in python I have tried this code but it shows an error:
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Error message: 
End of script output before headers: bounding_color_objects.py

```
#!c:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
print('Content-type: text/html\r\n')
print('\r\n')
import cv2
import numpy as np

image_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h,_,_ = cv2.split(image_hsv)
bins = np.bincount(h.flatten())
MIN_PIXEL_CNT_PCT = (1.0/20.0)
peaks = np.where(bins > (h.size * MIN_PIXEL_CNT_PCT))[0]

for i, peak in enumerate(peaks):
mask = cv2.inRange(h, peak, peak)
blob = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for j, contour in enumerate(contours):
bbox = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
contour_mask = np.zeros_like(mask)
cv2.drawContours(contour_mask, contours, j, 255, -1)

region = blob.copy()[bbox[1]:bbox[1]+bbox[3],bbox[0]:bbox[0]+bbox[2]]
region_mask = contour_mask[bbox[1]:bbox[1]+bbox[3],bbox[0]:bbox[0]+bbox[2]]
region_masked = cv2.bitwise_and(region, region, mask=region_mask)

result = cv2.bitwise_and(blob, blob, mask=contour_mask)
top_left, bottom_right = (bbox[0], bbox[1]), (bbox[0]+bbox[2], bbox[1]+bbox[3])
cv2.rectangle(result, top_left, bottom_right, (255, 255, 255), 2)

cv2.imshow('image',result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your code and result.

Comment: I have just added what I did